# Create custom selector

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, drawable

I've got 3 `TextView`, and I want to create a custom `selector` `drawable` which:

- creates a rectangular border with round corners (done)
- gets selected when the user presses one of them

The `TextView`s:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/info" android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tour1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tour \n disponibili  \n 21"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tour2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tour1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tour \n prenotabili  \n 16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tour3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tour2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tour \n preferiti  \n 3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My `Drawable` `selector` file, `back.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <stroke android:width="1dip"
            android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
        <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item  android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke android:width="5dip"
            android:color="#ff0000"/>
        <corners android:radius="7dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I would like to know how:

- to successfully apply the attribute `"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
- or, as I just tried to do, to apply a custom one.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to implement any of the above.  In my example, the `TextView`s always show the first item (the one without the `android:state_pressed="true"` attribute) selected and when I press them they never switch to the item with the `android:state_pressed="true"` attribute.

Where are the flaws in my code?

Comment: Try to use Button instead Textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying roarster's suggestion, you have to make TextViews clickable using `android:clickable="true"`

The order of the items in the selector is important, because the selector will pick the first (from the top) item that matches the state of the view, therefore, the "default" state (with no android:state_* defined) should be last, otherwise it will always match.

Comment: thank you, it worked!!  and how do I apply the attribute `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`?

Comment: Set the background for your view: `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
But, since you want to provide a custom drawable for selectableItemBackground, you need to override it in your Theme (and ensure the Activity that loads your layout is using the theme) using `<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/back</item>`

Answer (score 2):

Try swapping the order of the two items, I think that matters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke android:width="5dip"
            android:color="#ff0000"/>
        <corners android:radius="7dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <stroke android:width="1dip"
            android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
        <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**edit**

In fact, you may need to put the descriptions of the items in separate files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: @CrisBenois yeah, I thought of another thing that's tripped me up before and added it as an edit

Comment: Try using `<item  android:state_pressed="false">` for the non-pressed state.